# Introducing Push Notifications when Merge Request updated

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

Cases exist when a Merge Request (from now on `MR`) that is being under review is updated by a new push.
Is there a way to introduce push notifications (or any type of notifications besides email) that the `MR` under review has been updated?

Basically, if you have the `MR` open in a browser and reviewing it, to get a notification that it has changed, so you can refresh and review the latest code.

**EDIT**

When I say push notifications, I mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_Notification) not notifications for every push. Live notifications as I have the `MR` open (just like a hangouts message, or a facebook notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project, under `Settings ➔ Integrations`

You can select `Merge Request events`

(This URL will be triggered when a merge request is created/updated/merged)

You need to specify a URL where the data will be sent when a events is recorded, so on your side you should build something who listen and process the data

On your case you only want `MR` so you only check the `Merge Request events` and only events related to `MR` will be triggered

Your URL endpoint will receive a Request Header `X-Gitlab-Event: Merge Request Hook` with all the informations and you can push this to whatever you want

---

You can use webhook to build your own notification systems (Slack bot, Browser plugin and more)

[More info about the gitlab webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)

There also some pre-build services on the same setting page

[More info about gitlab services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/project_services.html)

Comment: You did not link the actual hook though. Also on the settings my fork of the project or on the main project settings?

Comment: I can't provide you a link, you need to build your own


You need to specify a URL where the data will be sent when a events is recorded, so on your side you should build something who listen and process the data

On your case you only want `MR` so you only check the `Merge Request events` and only events related to `MR` will be triggered


Your URL endpoint will receive a Request Header `X-Gitlab-Event: Merge Request Hook` will all the informations and you can push this to whatever you want


I suggest to setup this on the Main project

Comment: At first I thought you were providing a webhook (the wording of "this webhook" confused me.) Ok. Thanks for your help, accepted